# class instance cannot be resolved

Tags: java, scope

I have the following code

```
if (player.femaleBool)
    {
        player.trueName = player.maleNames[nameNum[0]];
        femGame gamePlay = new femGame();
    }//end if
    else
    {
        player.trueName = player.femNames[nameNum[0]];
        maleGame gamePlay = new maleGame();
    }//end else
gamePlay.tutorial();
```

I am running into an error where gamePlay cannot be resolved. Is this because of it being nested in the if stetments? If so is there any way I can work around it? It should be scoped to the main function of this class.

Comment: Yes, it is.  What is the common superclass / interface that femGame and maleGame both subclass / implement?

Comment: don't you have male and female reversed here?

Comment: Safe to assume that a maleGame contains a maile character, so a female player wants a male game.  Plus, that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: off topic suggestions: mind the naming convention and style.  By convention, the class name should be `FemGame` and `MaleGame` instead of `femGame` and `maleGame`.  To give more readable name, it should be `FemaleGame` and `MaleGame`.  The boolean variable should be something like `isFemale` instead of `femaleBool`.  Or even better, it should be something like an enum so that it looks like `if (player.gender == FEMALE)`.  Also mind your indentation.  `else` should be on same level as `if`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, in my code the format is not as messed up, must have been through to copying, I will keep in mind the camel casing differences for future projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is out of scope:

```csharp
gamePlay.tutorial();
```

gameplay exist only inside the if condition. But you can use polymorphism:

```csharp
//your classes must implement a interface:
public interface IGame
{
    void tutorial();
}
public class femGame: IGame
{
    public void tutorial()
    {
        //implementation...
    }
}
public class maleGame: IGame
{
    public void tutorial()
    {
        //implementation...
    }
}

//...

//using plymorphism:

IGame gamePlay;
if (player.femaleBool)
    {
        player.trueName = player.maleNames[nameNum[0]];
        gamePlay = new femGame();
    }//end if
    else
    {
        player.trueName = player.femNames[nameNum[0]];
        gamePlay = new maleGame();
    }//end else
gamePlay.tutorial();
```

Instead of an interface you can use a [abstract] class.

Comment: This will do perfectly, thank you, now that I know where to look I should be able to get this working.